# Google sheets Product function with Month comparison

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I want to multiply a range by another range in another sheet only If a month in a date from a range matches the month in another range in another sheet.

Technically:

**Multiply $R$8:$R$1007 by Start!$L$13:$L$24 If ARRAYFORMULA(TEXT($N$8:$N$1007,"MMMM")),"="&Start!$K$13:$K$24**

Edit: here's a sample of my tables:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1A0zZ1BvRnjeQQjsf4RoRGesOPNYOJWzlr9Kh2oYto-Y/edit?usp=sharing

I want the income from US dollars to another currency with conditions.

So in other words column T in sheet Transactions to be equal to the multiplication of the income in US dollars by the exchange rate in column L in sheet Start only If the month from column N equals in sheet Transactions the column K in sheet Start.

How can I right turn this into a functional formula, please?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide a table or link to a sheet displaying samples of your data and desired results. Are the two ranges more than 1 value? This could be done using `SUMPRODUCT`.

Comment: Can you please check the post now, I have updated it with more info and table sample!

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(MONTH(N8:N), 
 {MONTH(Start!K13:K24&1), Start!L13:L24}, 2, )*R8:R))
```

[image]

Comment: It worked man! I added little adjustments because I don't have unlimited rows:

=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(MONTH(N8:N1007), {MONTH(Start!$K$13:$K$24&1), Start!$L$13:$L$24}, 2, )*R8:R1007))

Answer (score 0):

Based on the limited information of your sheets. The following would multiply and sum each range if the months are matching:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(TEXT(N8:N1007,"mmmm")=Start!K13:K24),R8:R1007,Start!L13:L24)
```

Comment: Can you please check the post now, I have updated it with more info and table sample!